# Can Tarray constructor be aborted to not add new record?

Tags: arrays, delphi, generics, delphi-10.1-berlin

I am trying to control, limit how many new records are being added into array. Here is a simplified example:

I am trying to have variable LimitToUSA that will only let Developers from Country = US to be created in array:

```
type
  TDevelopers = record
    FName: string;
    LName: string;
    Country: string;
    constructor New(const aFName, aLName, aCountry: string);
  end;

var
  Developers:TArray<TDevelopers>;
  LimitToUSA: boolean; // <-- Controlling variable

constructor TDevelopers.New(const aFName, aLName, aCountry: string);
begin
  if LimitToUSA And (aCountry <> 'US') then
   Exit; // <-- Cancel adding new record here

  FName := aFName;
  LName := aLName;
  Country := aCountry;
end;

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  LimitToUSA := True;

  Developers := TArray<TDevelopers>.Create(
    TDevelopers.New('John','Smith', 'US'),
    TDevelopers.New('Leo','Hazen', 'CA'),
    TDevelopers.New('Bob','Tilson','UK'),
    TDevelopers.New('Jennifer','Wolken','US'),
    TDevelopers.New('John','Willer','US'));
end;
```

The problem is that it adds empty records for non-US Developers:

[image]

This solution is ugly when you 50 developers and it become annoying to maintain:

```
  if LimitToUSA then
  begin
    Developers := TArray<TDevelopers>.Create(
      TDevelopers.New('John','Smith', 'US'),
      TDevelopers.New('Jennifer','Wolken','US'),
      TDevelopers.New('John','Willer','US'));
  end
  else
  begin
    Developers := TArray<TDevelopers>.Create(
      TDevelopers.New('John','Smith', 'US'),
      TDevelopers.New('Leo','Hazen', 'CA'),
      TDevelopers.New('Bob','Tilson','UK'),
      TDevelopers.New('Jennifer','Wolken','US'),
      TDevelopers.New('John','Willer','US'));
  end;
```

**Is it possible to somehow cancel adding new record based on condition with constructor?**

Comment: You can't do that with a dynamic array constructor. What you are looking for is a generic list rather than an array constructor. That will give you the flexibility you need. Even so, your entire design is badly broken. Your record type should not have any knowledge about populating containers of that record type. That logic needs to be at a higher level.

Comment: I second what David says about the design. Put all developers into one list and then filter that depending on your needs. That way you can easily get those from US, UK, CA, whatever whenever you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't do that. What you can do is use a `TList<TDevelopers>` and only add valid class instances:

```
type
  TDevelopers = record
    LName: string;
    FName: string;
    Country: string;
    constructor New(const aFName, aLName, aCountry: string);
  end;

const
  NumDevelopers = 5; // or whatever the real number is.
  ConstDevelopers: array[0..NumDevelopers - 1] of TDevelopers =
  (
    (LName: 'Smith'; FName: 'John'; Country: 'US'),
    (LName: 'Wolken'; FName: 'Jennifer'; Country: 'US'),
    (LName: 'Hazen'; FName: 'Leo'; Country: 'CA'),
    (LName: 'Tilson'; FName: 'Bob'; Country: 'UK'),
    (LName: 'Willer'; FName: 'John'; Country: 'US')
  );

...

var
  Developers: TList<TDevelopers>;
  I: Integer;
begin
  Developers := TList<TDevelopers>.Create;
  for I := 0 to High(ConstDevelopers) do
  begin
    if not LimitToUSA or (ConstDevelopers[I].Country = 'US') then
      Developers.Add(ConstDevelopers[I]);
  end;
```

Now, if you really need an array, you can use ToArray.

**Note that I can't test this code right now** (at the moment, I can only start this Mac in Safe Mode and then I can't start Parallels with the Windows VM). **But it should give you a hint at what you can do.**

### Alternative

Alternatively, you keep your code and simply remove all records that are empty (check for `Country = ''`). In the latest Delphi versions (including *Berlin*), you can delete from dynamic arrays, using `Delete`, like `Delete` for strings. But go about it backwards, otherwise you'll get in trouble with your index:

```
for I := High(Developers) downto 0 do
  if Developers[I].Country = '' then
    Delete(Developers, I, 1);
```

### Alternative 2

To avoid having to repeat yourself, you can do:

```
  Developers := TArray<TDevelopers>.Create(
    TDevelopers.New('John','Smith', 'US'),
    TDevelopers.New('Jennifer','Wolken','US'),
    TDevelopers.New('John','Willer','US'));
  if not LimitToUSA then
  begin
    ForeignDevelopers := TArray<TDevelopers>.Create(
      TDevelopers.New('Leo','Hazen', 'CA'),
      TDevelopers.New('Bob','Tilson','UK'));
    Developers := Developers + ForeignDevelopers;
  end;
```

Comment: Very good! In this case `constructor New` is not needed, right?

Comment: @Mike: I don't know if you might need it for something else, e.g. adding a new developer not on the constant list yet (a new hire), at a later date, but otherwise, it can be discarded.

Comment: The list is more versatile anyway. It is easier to add or remove people from it than from a TArray, although you can do that too.